# In Sharepoint Designer is there a condition to see if a approval workflow and a review workflow is approved or completed?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to toggle a field when an approval workflow is approved and when a review workflow is approved. I don't see any conditions that call that in SharePoint Designer 2010.

I have tried calling it using "If current item equals field" using 
Data Source: Current Item
Field from Source: "Name of workflow" but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once a workflow is associated to a list or library SharePoint automatically adds a Field (Normally the workflow name). This field will store status of that workflow.

To check if workflow is completed you can compare this field to value 5

To check if workflow is approved you can compare this field to value 16